# Jquery NumberFormatter Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using NumberFormmater to format a number i have included a js file and wrote a simple code but it is not working. i am following this link http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/.

```
$('#txtNumber').formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**locale:"en"** has an issue as per a link provided by you there is no locale like **"en"**
if you want to do it for United States then try **"us"**

as well as `no function like format`

try

```
.formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
```

**EDIT**

```
    $("#txtNumber").blur(function(){
    $(this).parseNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    $(this).formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
    });
```

have you written code like it?

you also need to add libraries first download all js then include it as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jshashtable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numberformatter-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $('#txtNumber').formatNumber({format:"#,###.00", locale:"us"}); but still not working

Comment: i had tried it with blur but it was not working with that either.

Comment: is there any issue with the library which i have included

Comment: is the code same as the edit? can you show me how you added the library?

Comment: i haven't included jshashtable. i will download it rite now. and will let u know.

Comment: u mentioned to include jshashtable.js first then jquery-min.js. Is it not like this to include jquery first then jshashtable and then numberformatter

Comment: ya i just forget to set the sequence the sequence you have specified is right.. go on with it

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from [the plugin page you linked](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/), there is no `format` function offered by the plugin. There are `parseNumber` and `formatNumber`. Both are available on jQuery instances (they use/set the `val()` of the element), or as members of the `jQuery` object itself (you pass them the data to use and receive the result as a return value). All of this is quite clearly laid out on that page.

Also note that the plugin requires [jshashtable](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/), perhaps you aren't including it?

And see also [Hemant's note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727154/157247) that there is no "en" locale listed as supported. You may want "us", "gb", "au", or...